# Search and Copy through batch file

Tags: search, batch-file, xcopy

I would like to search all word files in .doc and .docx extensions from C and D drives then copy then to F drive the script which i want have to use xcopy command any suggestions

Comment: or you can also use vbs if u can

Comment: Please consult the help section about what kind of questions are accepted and appropriate to ask on this website and what you can do to improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

`*.doc` will match `*.doc` and `*.docx`

```
xcopy "c:\*.doc" "f:\target folder\c\" /s
xcopy "d:\*.doc" "f:\target folder\d\" /s
```